# Salesforce OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow: INVALID_SESSION_ID

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce

I've been trying to test out the OAuth flow on my connected app, but I get the following behaviour:

1. Authorize the app:

   > https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&
   >       client_id=theclientid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com
2. Login to Salesforce, Click "Allow" on "RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage"
3. Page redirects to mysite.com. Using "access_token" in URL, make the following cURL call

   > curl -X GET
   >   https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Account -H
   >   'Authorization: Bearer thetoken' -H 'X-PrettyPrint:1'
4. Response:

   > {
   >   "message" : "Session expired or invalid",
   >   "errorCode" : "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
   >   }

I've also tried the "OAuth Refresh Token Process" with the token I get from 1. however that also fails with:

> { error_description: "expired access/refresh token" error:
>   "invalid_grant" }

I tried converting the %21 to ! in the URL encoded access_token, but that didn't help.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @dpk, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Comment: Hi Ralph. I'll keep that in mind and I may even move this over there.

Comment: We see around 20-25 questions per day on the Salesforce StackExchange (vs the 4 or so over here).  So you'll definitely get a lot more attention over there :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the cURL call was malformed. I had to replace the '%21' with '!' and also change the header from 'Bearer' to 'OAuth'.

Comment: I am having the same request but then too I am not able to authorized the request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a step after getting to

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token& client_id=theclientid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com
```

You'll need to enter the login details and then you'll get redirected to the callback url you set up in your connected app settings which will include the access token you can use to authenticate your app.

Comment: I've updated my description. I was already entering my login details and clicking "Allow" on the authorization page. Any other ideas?